# Player API issues after YouTube watch page displas a pre-roll ad

Tags: youtube-api

When surfing to a Youtube page (for instance http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=BfOdWSiyWoc) and it got a pre-roll advertisment (a video ad which is displayed before the clip itself) the entire player API get screwed up in regard to the original video.

For instance, the player.getCurrentTime() & player.getDuration() return the ad data when the ad is being displayed but after the video is being switched to the desired video they keep returning 0 (the video is being played correctly and the video player does show how much time was played and how long is the clip). btw, this behaviour does not happen if there wasn't an ad.

Also, if during the desired video I call player.getVideoUrl() then I get the ad url and not the video url (only if there was a pre-roll ad of course).

I tried to reset it in various ways (stop and then load the desired video, clone the player and reset it, etc...) but couldnt find a working solution, anyone got an idea?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: Sure, just open the developer tools of the browser and type the following code at the console during a pre-roll ad:  console.log(document.getElementById('movie_player').getCurrentTime()+' == '+document.getElementById('movie_player').getDuration());

During the playing of the ad it will return the relevant results, but after skipping the ad (or waiting till it end) the actual video will return to the exact same code the values 0 == 0 or if u skipped, the last values which were shown by the ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you're attempting to use the YouTube Player API to control playback on a YouTube.com watch page. (If that's not the case, you need to edit your question to clarify what you're actually doing.)

There is no support for using the Player API to control playback on a YouTube.com watch page. It might be possible to hack something together as part of a browser extension, but if you do, expect breakage.

The Player API is only meant to control playback of embedded YouTube players on third-party web pages.

Comment: Indeed it's a browser extension and so far it worked really good so I thought that I can base my code on that, I guess that I'll try to replace the player each time its loaded with an embedded one, will update if that will work correctly (and mark the answer as a right one). thx!